# ExecuteFunction not invoking the function

Tags: office-js

I have created a Microsoft Office Add-in React (TypeScript) Project using [`yo office`](https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office).

I have changed my `manifest.xml` to include

```
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.GrabSelectionButton">
  <Label resid="Contoso.GrabSelectionButton.Label" />
  <Supertip>
    <Title resid="Contoso.GrabSelectionButton.Label" />
    <Description resid="Contoso.GrabSelectionButton.Tooltip" />
  </Supertip>
  <Icon>
    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
  </Icon>

  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
    <FunctionName>grabSelection</FunctionName>
  </Action>
</Control>
```

The `<FunctionFile resid="Contoso.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" />` is set correctly - I did not change it from the template default.

I added the method in `function-file.ts` like this

```
(() => {
  Office.initialize = () => { console.log("this gets logged..."); };

  function grabSelection(event){
    console.log("grabSelection invoked! - this does not get logged");

    event.completed();
  }

})();
```

and I have also tried like this

```
   (() => {
      Office.initialize = () => { console.log("this gets logged..."); };
    })();

export function grabSelection(event){
  console.log("grabSelection invoked! - this does not get logged");
  event.completed();
}
```

I can see it compiled and included at runtime but the function does not get invoked...

why is the function not being invoked? Is it a problem with `webpack` not exporting the function correctly?

Comment: turns out others have stumbled across this issue: https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office/issues/424

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by attaching my function to the global namespace like this:

```
(() => {
  Office.initialize = () => {
    console.log("function file loaded...!");
   };
  })();

function grabSelection(event: any): void {
    console.log("i got invoked!!!");
    event.completed();
}

const _global = (window /* browser */ || global /* node */) as any;
_global.grabSelection= grabSelection;
```